# Exception: Specified cast is not valid.v

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2

```
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.TypeMap.FromValue(Object oValue, Int32& iByteLength, DB2Connection connection, Int32 iArrayLength, String parameterName, Boolean bMultiRowCmd)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Parameter.GetParamInfo(Int32 paramPos, DB2ParamInfo& paramInfo, Boolean chainBegin)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ParameterCollection.GetParamInfoList(Boolean chainBegin)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, DB2CursorType reqCursorType, Boolean abortOnOptValueChg, Boolean skipDeleted, Boolean isResultSet, Int32 maxRows, Boolean skipInitialValidation)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Command.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Exception was thrown at location where it has below lines of code.
**var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()**

we have no issue with dotnet core 2.1 but when we updated to dotnet core 3.1 we are running into this issue.

**update**
dotnetcore 2.1 project used ibm.data.db2.core 1.3
dotnetcore 3.1 project using ibm.data.db2.core 3.1(Unit test is passing though)

Comment: Have you verified that the library versions are identical after upgrading? Most likely they are not and you would need to raise something with the library developer.

Comment: There were bugs in 2.1 that was fixed on 3.1.   So the error is probably real and just never caught in 2.1.

Comment: @DavidL i updated the question of versions i am using and also unit test is passing but when i call the microservice it fails.

Comment: Have you checked your model datatypes match the table datatypes? This error often appears when you have mismatched types like the db table has an int (4 byte int) but the c# model has a short (2 byte int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now.
In dotnet core 2.1 the object value deserializes properly. In my case it is string where as in dotnet core 3.1 it is deserializes as JsonElement  which was causing the issue and db2 was not recognizing the jsonelement as any type.

I switched my service to use Newtonsoftjson by adding
`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` 
and now it is properly desearilizing it.

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29960) for bool which is pretty much the same as my case but my object is of type string. They also suggest there to write a custom converter for Object.

Answer (score 0):

**In case someone stumbles upon this issue:**

While one should configure desiralization properly, as pointed out by the accepted answer, in my case, I was trying to convert `CHARACTER(1)` SQL Type to `char` data type which is the same as `Int32`.

The solution was to change the `char` data type to `string`. Inefficient but it does the job.